# Axios - Sending always default header

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an app where most of the endpoints use the same token to authenticate. So, when a user logs in I use the following:

`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + user.access_token`

But I have some endpoints that have a different Bearer token. In these cases, I'm trying this:

```
axios.get(`${API_BASE}/Config`, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      commit(HIDE_LOADING)
      resolve(response.data)
    }
  })
```

Where `AuthStr` is being passed in as an argument and is the correct Bearer Token for this endpoint. But when I call this method, axios is sending the Bearer Token configured on `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']` and is ignoring my `AuthStr` token argument.

How can I override this?

Comment: It's a known [bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/382). Please use any workaround that suits your needs, from the issue tracker I linked.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought this bug had been fixed in release v0.19.0-beta.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Maaz Syed Adeeb this is an axios bug. I could solve using the following code as suggested in: [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/382)

```
  axios.get(`${API_BASE}/EndPointThatUserAnotherToken`, getAxiosOptions(AuthStr))
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      commit(HIDE_LOADING)
      resolve(response.data)
    }
  })

function getAxiosOptions (authToken) {
  let opt = {
    transformRequest: [function (data, headers) {
      delete headers.common.Authorization
      headers.Authorization = authToken
      return data
      }]
    }
    return opt
}
```